# CSS @media queries on Samsung Galaxy S III

Tags: android, css, media-queries

I'm working on a website with responsive design and mobile optimization.
I'm having issues targeting the Samsung Galaxy S III default browser, as it  **does not** scale font-sizes.

The funny thing is that everything works fine using Google Chrome for Android on the same device, so I don't think there is a problem with my @media queries. Of course I've triple checked them and I am sure the Galaxy S III displays fits in them. All the other conditional styles apply, except for font-sizes.

Everything works well on other Android based devices, eg the Samsung Galaxy Nexus's default browser.

Is there anything I should do to target The Galaxy S III default browser? Does it interpret in some funny way font sizes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer one of your questions yes it does interpret font size in a odd way. The Samsung GS3 default browser is pretty bad in that regards. I am not really sure there is a work around on it. I can't imagine too many people are using the default browser anyways.

Comment: The way it scales font sizes is based on user settings on the default browser. With them disabled user-side pages display correctly. Within the browser settings you can scale font to 50% to 200%. I do not think there is a way around this other than the person using the phone fixing their settings.

Comment: I see... Thanks, this at least points me in some direction. I'll investigate.